# How to get sum/difference From a different sheet using dates as reference?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Collections Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/587sR.png)

[Expenses Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ137.png)

Hi, I would like to get the daily sum/difference of the expenses from the expenses sheet then output to collections sheet using dates as reference/identifier.

I tried this code `=MINUS(C8,INDEX(Expenses!20:31,12,2))` but I want it to auto compute when I drag the box. sorry for bad english. thank you

Desired output:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh0Yo.png)

Output at (Net) Cash On Hand Row / Reference Date Column, the output should  be August 1 Collection - August 1 Expenses.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is with the structure of your expense sheet, since you need to use only every second column. For this you can use various methods, something like

```
=split(substitute(join(";",Expenses!A2:DJ2),"Total:;",""),";")
```

The `join` function takes the whole row and joins it into one string, the `substitute` function removes the `Total:` from it, along with the trailing `;` and the `split` function separates it again to separate values. This will be an array, automatically spread out to 31(-ish) columns width if entered into a cell like `C10` on your Collections sheet.

Then you have two options, simply do `=C8-C10` in `C9`, which you can drag with no problem. You can also hide the row 10 by making the text color white, or even integrate it in that sheet.

My recommendation however is not to do any of that, instead enter the formula

```
=arrayformula(C8:AG8 - split(substitute(join(";",Expenses!A2:DJ2),"Total:;",""),";")
```

into `C9` on the Collections sheet and it's taken care of, without the need to drag it out. You might need to tweak it, not sure if the `AG8` and `DJ2` are the correct columns to end them on (should be the last column if every column or every 2 columns is a day). The `arrayformula` makes sure that the subtractions are done automatically for each pair of values, and expanded automatically into the row. Make sure that there are no values or formulas in `D9:AG9`, so it can fill up the values automatically and you don't get a `#REF` error.